# NHibernate 5 Criteria must use equivalent of LINQ .Contains()

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

We have a NHibernate V5 project were some queries need improvement.
We had one query using ICriteria like this:

```
var list = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(ClockEntry))
        .Add(Restrictions.And(
                        Restrictions.Ge("Time", startDate),
                        Restrictions.Le("Time", endDate)
                    ))
                    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
                        .Add(Projections.Property("Id"))
                        .Add(Projections.Property("Time"))
                )

.List<IList>()
.Select(ce => new ClockEntry() { Id = (Guid)ce[0], Time = (DateTime)ce[1] });
```

The last line of code (the Select) creates a new ClockEntry list where ONLY the Id and Time retain values. All other fields (columns) are null.

We then wrote a new query using NHibernate Query where the "Contains" element was added.
This is as follows:

```
    var p = Rules.UserDataFilters.UserPayrollFilterNumbers(user, session, false);
    var s = Rules.UserDataFilters.UserSiteFilterCodes(user, session);

    ClockEntryRepository clockEntryRepository = new ClockEntryRepository(session);
        var r = clockEntryRepository
            .Query()
            .Where(c =>
                c.Time >= startDate &&
                c.Time <= endDate &&
                p.Contains(c.Employee.Payroll.Number) &&
                s.Contains(c.Employee.Site.Code));
```

Notice the added 'p' and 's' constraints

The problem:
I am unable to find the correct construct to add the 'Contains' into the first code block
and I am unable to find a elegant way in which to achieve the Select statement in the 2nd example.
Obviously either one will do but I would greatly appreciate input for answers for both scenarios.

Comment: `.Select(c => new ClockEntry() { Id = c.Id, Time = c.Time})` should work  for `Query`

Comment: Thanks @Roman - That confirms that the Select is capable of transforming the query into a result where only the Id and Time elements remain. I have found the answer for the ICriteria sample.

Answer (score 0):

The Icriteria query "p" and "s" items I managed to resolve once I figured out that in SQL this would be a IN construct so it became:

```
var list = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(ClockEntry))
    .Add(Restrictions.Ge("Time", strtDate))
    .Add(Restrictions.Le("Time", entDate))
    .Add(Restrictions.In("PayrollNo", p))
    .Add(Restrictions.In("SiteCode", s))

    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.Property("Id"))
        .Add(Projections.Property("Time")))
    .List<IList>()
    .Select(ce => new ClockEntry() { Id = (Guid)ce[0], Time = (DateTime)ce[1]});
            
return list.ToList();
```